# Fixing memory leak for below code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

i hav a problem in fixing memory leak for retuned array,how do i fix the memory leak for the below array ?

```
    NSMutableArray *retArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    [retArr insertObject:[arr objectAtIndex:i] atIndex:i];
}
[arr release];
return retArr;
```

Comment: you have to release retArr as well

Comment: Post the entire method, including the method signature.

Comment: Anything preventing you from autoreleasing retArr?

Comment: needs more information than this (e.g. what line are you seeing a leak coming from)?  are you using ARC?

Comment: showing memory leak in the first line

Comment: return [retArr autorelease]; worked

Answer (score 3):

You should normally autorelease your return values, unless the method name starts with new, alloc, copy or mutableCopy.

```
return [retArr autorelease];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW6

Answer (score 2):

Use autorelease on the NSMutableArray

```
NSMutableArray *retArr = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10] autorelease];
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    [retArr insertObject:[arr objectAtIndex:i] atIndex:i];
}
[arr release];
return retArr;
```

Comment: Also something like this might be a bit nicer than the loop method you are using

 NSRange range = NSMakeRange (0, 10);

 NSIndexSet *indexes = [NSIndexSet initWithIndexesInRange:range];

 NSMutableArray *retArr = [[[arr objectsAtIndexes:indexes] mutablecopy] autorelease];
 
 [arr release];
 
 return retArr;

Comment: Post the entire method then, because it must be something else.

Comment: If I have answered your question please mark my answer as correct. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to autorelease the array and put it in an autoreleasepool, so that it can be autoreleased after some time.

```
NSMutableArray *retArr = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10] autorelease];
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use autorelease on the array:

```
NSMutableArray *retArr = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10] autorelease];
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
[retArr insertObject:[arr objectAtIndex:i] atIndex:i];

    }

[arr release];
return retArr;
```